# Physical Realizability of Outer product

Tags: quantum-operation

I have a quantum state $|\Psi\rangle$ of $n$ qubits whose exact coefficients/probabilities I do not know.
I want to operate another unknown quantum state $|\Phi\rangle$ with $U = a|\Psi\rangle \langle \Psi| - B$ where $B$ is a fixed known matrix and $a$ is a known fixed scalar such that $U$ is unitary.
i.e., I want to do $U|\Phi\rangle$ and get output and use the same $U$ and apply on multiple unknown quantum states.

Is this physically realizable or doable? If so how?

Is it necessary to measure $|\Psi\rangle$ to do this or there is a way to apply $U$ on unknown quantum states without actually measuring $|\Psi\rangle$?

Comment: Small comment: if $a$ and $B$ are known and you guarantee that $U$ is unitary, the set of possible states $|\Psi\rangle$ is significantly restricted (so it is far from completely unknown)

Comment: Not necessarily. There are $a,B$ such that the state $\Psi$, still can be arbitrary and $U$ is still unitary.

Comment: Yes, but your question goes in the opposite direction: assume $a$ and $B$ are known and that $\Psi$ is unknown. In that case, $\Psi$ is not completely unknown. I agree that for every $\Psi$ one should be able to find some $a$ and $B$

Comment: Any thoughts ? anyone ?

Comment: @Balajisb Can you give an example of an $a$ and $B$ such that every possible $|\Psi\rangle$ makes $U$ unitary? Because I am having difficulty seeing it, beyond $a=0$.

Comment: @JahanClaes $a=2$, $B=I$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take your example, $a=1,B=2$. Given a state $|\Psi\rangle\otimes|\Phi\rangle$, and we want to apply some unitary operator that sends this state to $|\Psi\rangle \otimes \Big(2|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|-1\Big)|\Phi\rangle$. Note that we need the state $|\Psi\rangle$ to be preserved, if we want to use this operation multiple times. Luckily, this problem has already been considered in https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4032, where the proved such an operation does not exist. In fact, they proved that even if we relax the condition to having an output $|\Psi'\rangle \otimes \Big(2|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|-1\Big)|\Phi\rangle$ for some new state $|\Psi'\rangle$, no such unitary exists. I'll be honest, I can't follow the notation in their paper. But I can give a pretty simple argument for the case $|\Psi'\rangle=|\Psi\rangle$:

> Let $U$ be the unknown unitary, and let $|\Psi_1\rangle\otimes|\Phi\rangle$ and $|\Psi_2\rangle\otimes|\Phi\rangle$ be two states that we want to apply $U$ to. I'll assume we have the same $|\Phi\rangle$ for simplicity, because I don't need to assume different $|\Phi\rangle$s to reach a contradiction. Then we have
> $$ U\Big(|\Psi_1\rangle\otimes|\Phi\rangle\Big)=|\Psi_1\rangle\otimes\Big(2|\Psi_1\rangle\langle\Psi_1|\Phi\rangle-|\Phi\rangle\Big) $$
> $$ U\Big(|\Psi_2\rangle\otimes|\Phi\rangle\Big)=|\Psi_2\rangle\otimes\Big(2|\Psi_2\rangle\langle\Psi_2|\Phi\rangle-|\Phi\rangle\Big) $$
> Note that unitary matrices preserve inner products, so we have
> $$ \langle\Psi_1|\Psi_2\rangle = \langle\Psi_1|\Psi_2\rangle\Big(1-2\langle\Phi|\Psi_1\rangle\langle\Psi_1|\Phi\rangle-2\langle\Phi|\Psi_2\rangle\langle\Psi_2|\Phi\rangle+4\langle\Phi|\Psi_1\rangle\langle\Psi_1|\Psi_2\rangle\langle\Psi_2|\Phi\rangle\Big)$$
> $$ 1 = \Big(1-2\langle\Phi|\Psi_1\rangle\langle\Psi_1|\Phi\rangle-2\langle\Phi|\Psi_2\rangle\langle\Psi_2|\Phi\rangle+4\langle\Phi|\Psi_1\rangle\langle\Psi_1|\Psi_2\rangle\langle\Psi_2|\Phi\rangle\Big)$$
> You should already suspect that this is an equation that couldn't possibly be satisfied for all $|\Psi_i\rangle$ and $|\Phi\rangle$. But Let's get an actual contradiction for some specific values of $|\Psi_i\rangle$ and $|\Phi_i\rangle\rangle$. Let's choose $\langle\Psi_2|\Psi_1\rangle=1/2$ and $|\Phi\rangle=|\Psi_1\rangle$. Then this equation becomes
> $$1=1-2-2(1/2)^2+4(1/2)^2=-1/2.$$
> So no such $U$ exists.

This proof can probably be applied to other choices of $a,B$.

Comment: Hi...Very much thanks for your answer...If you assume $<\Psi_1,\Psi_2> = 0$ then you are canceling out $<\Psi_1,\Psi_2>$ is your derivation which is canceling out $0$. Can you check your proof ?

Comment: I understood the proof give in the paper you mentioned but the proof works only when $<\Psi_1,\Psi_2> \neq 0$.. But thanks a ton for this answer... cheers ! :-)

Comment: Good point! Let’s assume the overlap is just less than one.